# after using varnish and nginx ssl termination, all the online customer ip changed to 127.0.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx, ssl, varnish

after using varnish and use Nginx SSL termination for varnish, today I found that all the online customer IP changed to 127.0.0.1

Apache2 8080 port

Varnish 80 port

Nginx 443 port

```
location / {
proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1;
proxy_read_timeout    90;
proxy_connect_timeout 90;
proxy_redirect        off;

proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 443;
proxy_set_header      Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Nginx on;
proxy_redirect     off;
```

extension: Turpentine for Varnish

Magento set both secure and unsecured URL to "https://"

[image]

how to fix this problem, I want to show the original IP of the customer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to `local.xml` and

```
clear/flush
```

magento cache.

code

```
 <remote_addr_headers>
     <header1>HTTP_X_REAL_IP</header1>
     <header2>HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</header2>
 </remote_addr_headers>
```